# HTML5 Audio Plays only when I step through javascript

Tags: asp.net, html, audio

I have an asp.net page with an  tag in it.  If I enable controls (controls="controls") I can play the audio assigned to the tag.  I just want to show my own button to play the audio, so I added a simple html button with a javascript function to hit the .play method:

```
<button id="LeftAudio" class="Audio" onclick="playAudio1()"></button>

function playAudio1() {
    // Check for audio element support.
    if (window.HTMLAudioElement) {
        try {
            //debugger;
            var oAudio = document.getElementById('dnn_ctr<%=ModuleId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>_ViewUFL_Book_audio1');
            oAudio.volume = 1.0;
            // Tests the paused attribute and set state. 
            if (oAudio.paused) {
                oAudio.play();
                debugger;
            }
            else {
                oAudio.pause();
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            // Fail silently but show in F12 developer tools console
            if (window.console && console.error("Error:" + e));
        }
    }
}
```

The audio plays fine when I step through the javascript (Chrome/Windows), but will not play at all if I am not debugging.  I tried putting the debugger; statement before the play command and stepping through the code, and putting it after the play command - both work.  Just doesn't work if I let it run normally.

Any ideas??

Comment: what browser are testing this on?

Answer (score 0):

I just made it on Fiddle and its working for me.

Here is the test on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwCXV/4/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that did not work on my system.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @user507522 I tested also with netscape and work. Do you see under the button the audio controls ?

Comment: I tested on chrome ver 23, and firefox 16

Comment: I see the audio controls and the button.  If I click play on the audio control itself it plays, but if I click on the button it will only play in debug.

Comment: when you say only works in debug, does this mean it doesn't work when published/uploaded elsewhere.  If that's the case is the audio file def published/uploaded as well?

Comment: @user1166905 Not the case.  I'm working on my local machine only at this point, so it's not an issue that the audio file can't be found.  The audio plays when I click the play button on the audio control itself, and plays if I step through the javascript, just doesn't play if I let the javascript run without debugging.

Comment: A bit of additional info just discovered: the audio starts to play but then stops after a fraction of a second when the javascript runs without debug.

Comment: Never did get this to work properly.  Abandoned in favor of jplayer.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MartyG well, maybe is better to use something that is more old, tested and compatible than this new one.